# Git: if A merges from B, and B independently merges from A without conflicts, can they be made the same commit?

Tags: git

For some context, I'm working on a distributed program that needs to do version management and conflict resolution in real-time with multiple collaborators, and I'm considering using Git (specifically https://github.com/creationix/js-git) under the hood. Each user will have their own ref, but there will be a global history (much like what GitHub does). But unlike GitHub, all users' forks should be equal, and pull requests are not one-directional into an upstream fork.

I'm considering a scenario where two users, having just made their own offline changes *[commits shown below as A and B]*, elect to each pull from their collaborator's development branch at the same time. Assuming that the merge is done with the same version of Git, and nothing remotely resembling a conflict is found, the two merges would end up with the same tree, but (as far as I know) since the users doing the merge commits have different names, the merge commits C and C' would have different hashes (and therefore be different).

```
  ...A---C
 /    \ /
O      /
 \    / \
  ...B---C'
```

The thing is, if there are not conflicts and the trees and parents in C and C' are identical, I'd really like to make them appear to be the same commit, if anything just to allow for easier fast-forwards in the future, and to permit a cleaner commit-graph presentation.

The way I see it, if the names, emails, and commit times were automatically set to be identical on the merge commits (i.e. merged by automerge@example.com at the latest commit time of the parents), then C and C' would be identical? So it would be equivalent to having pulled C/C' from an authoritative upstream source? Are there any pitfalls or dangers with this approach that I should be aware of? Or can Git handle this automatically with some functionality unknown to me?

Comment: How likely do you think it is that 2 people pull from each other at *exactly* the same time? In every other case, B will just pull C from A and fast-forward, so C' will never be created and your Problem doesn’t exist.

Comment: In this specific case, commits could be made instantly as the result of a mouse click or drag-and-drop on a GUI, so it's well within reason that this would happen within the second or so of network latency for international collaborators.

Comment: I understand that part, but that would still require those users to click the button at the exact same second. That will probably happen once a year, and if it does you get one unnecessary merge commit. You can think about whether it makes sense to write a lot of code to prevent that. Linus Torwalds obviously thought that it doesn’t ;).

Comment: [Honril Awmos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18688910/1256452) has the correct answer: the hashes will differ, even if all else is the same, as the parents are in the opposite orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the parents of C and C' are reversed. The first parent of C is A and the second parent is B (you merge commit B into the branch that has commit A). For C' it's the other way around (you merged commit A into the branch that has commit B).

Git saves the hashes of the parent commits in the commit object. The first hash that appears is the commit that the branch you are currently on points to. After that follows the hash of the commit(s) you are merging in.

The order matters when calculating the sha hash. Given that sha is pretty sensitive about these kind of changes, the chances of the two hashes being equal are virtually zero. Even if you manage to keep everything else the same. The fact that the commits are on two different branches is enough to throw off the sha hashes.

run `git cat-file -p branch-a` and `git cat-file -p branch-b` to see the difference. There will be two lines with `parent <sha1>` in there and the order is reversed.